# MySQL query that returns results for 2 values if either match query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to query 2 tables for matching values and return results if **either** condition matches.  Here are the tables showing only relevant columns...

```
scores
    scoreId int not null,
    comments varchar(128)

mediaComments
    contentId varchar(40) not null,
    scoreId int (foreign key to scores.scoreId)
```

I'd like to get values for both comments and contentId for the following criteria...

comments != ""
OR
contentId exists for scoreId

Here are the table values...

```
mysql> select * from mediaComments;
+---------+-----------------------------+
| scoreId | contentId                   |
+---------+-----------------------------+
|       1 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       2 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       4 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       6 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
+---------+-----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select scoreId, comments from scores;
+---------+---------------------------+
| scoreId | comments                  |
+---------+---------------------------+
|       1 |                           |
|       2 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods1 |
|       3 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods2 |
|       4 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods3 |
|       5 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods4 |
|       6 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods5 |
|       7 |                           |
|       8 |                           |
|       9 |                           |
+---------+---------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the simple query I'm using.

```
select
    s.scoreId,
    s.comments,
    m.contentId
from
    scores s,
    mediaComments m
where
    s.comments != '' or
    m.scoreId = s.scoreId;
```

I'm trying to get results if either comments or mediaComments have values.  If the values do not match the query, I'd like to have NULL returned.  For example, I'd like to have m.contentId be returned as NULL if s.scoreId is not found in mediaComments, but there is a value for s.comments.

Here is the results I'm getting...

```
mysql> select
    ->     s.scoreId,
    ->     s.comments,
    ->     m.contentId
    -> from
    ->     scores s,
    ->     mediaComments m
    -> where
    ->     s.comments != '' or
    ->     m.scoreId = s.scoreId;
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
| scoreId | comments                  | contentId                   |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
|       1 |                           | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       2 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods1 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       2 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods1 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       2 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods1 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       2 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods1 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
|       3 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods2 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       3 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods2 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       3 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods2 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       3 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods2 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
|       4 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods3 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       4 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods3 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       4 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods3 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       4 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods3 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
|       5 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods4 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       5 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods4 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       5 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods4 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       5 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods4 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
|       6 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods5 | CON-i6FYCiNDJ0u7mbGfttK8Joy |
|       6 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods5 | CON-RgNzMie5F8EdSnEq7122siV |
|       6 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods5 | CON-3bo1iGIBdu623TS4ltggytT |
|       6 | ReadScoreCommentsMethods5 | CON-qjMVn2THP6d2nCta9JWL1na |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
21 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select s.*
from scores s
where s.comment <> '' or
      exists (select 1
              from mediaComments mc
              where mc.scoreid = s.scoreid
             );
```

If you want `content_id` as well, then something like this:

```
select s.*, mc.contentid
from scores s left join
     mediaComments mc
     on mc.scoreid = s.scoreid
where s.comment <> null or mc.contentid is not null;
```

Comment: FIxed a couple typos and is works great!  select s.*, mc.contentId
from scores s left join
     mediaComments mc
     on mc.scoreId = s.scoreId
where s.comments <> '' or mc.contentId is not null;

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are asking for. 
However, you should probably use OUTER JOIN.
FULL OUTER JOIN returns everything from both tables whether it's null or not.

````sql
SELECT
    s.scoreId,
    s.comments,
    m.contentId
FROM
    scores as s 
    FULL OUTER JOIN mediaComments as m 
    ON s.scoreID = m.contentId;
```mysql
````